# Get a file's complete git status, including ignored, untracked, unmodified, modified

Tags: git, command-line, version-control

Sometimes I'll have a file in a git-controlled repository, and I'll want to know how git understands the file. Is it tracked and modified? Tracked but unmodified? Untracked and ignored? Untracked and not ignored?

Problem: the commands I know don't give complete information:

- `git status fileName`: shows nothing unless file is tracked and modified
- `git check-ignore fileName`: shows if a file is ignored, but shows nothing if untracked or tracked
- `git check-ignore --no-index fileName`: ignores the index, and so won't show whether file is tracked

Is there a git command (or series of commands) which will show everything git knows about a file (except perhaps any diff if modified)?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work here.  All `git ls-files <fileName>` does is either show or not show the file name, based on various flags. So, I can iterate through the flags and see when it appears or does not, but I'm guessing even that's not a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Sometimes I'll have a file in a git-controlled repository, and I'll want to know how Git understands the file.  Is it tracked and modified? Tracked but unmodified?  Untracked and ignored?  Untracked and not ignored?

This is fundamentally a bit tricky.

To test whether the file is *tracked*, see if it exists in the index.  You may first wish to test whether the index contains any unmerged entries, or inspect the potential matches for their staging slots.  As [phd suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72981379/get-a-files-complete-git-status-including-ignored-untracked-unmodified-modi#comment128901831_72981379), `git ls-files` is your plumbing command to use here, to tell whether the file is in Git's index.  Run `git ls-files --staged` to see if the file is in the index, and if so, at which slots.  If it is in the index (at all), it's tracked; if not, it's untracked.

Having decided whether the file is tracked or not, you now pass into two separate cases:

- An *untracked* file can either exist in the working tree, or not, and that's pretty much it for the file itself.  If it *does* exist in the working tree, it can be excluded, or not.  Use `git ls-files` with the `--others` option to see if it exists, and add `--exclude-standard` to see if it's ignored.
- A *tracked* file can either exist in the working tree, or not; if it doesn't exist in the working tree, it's considered "modified", and if it's modified as compared to the index version, `git ls-files --modified` will show it as modified.  So use `git ls-files` to check its status here.

  A tracked file can also be marked `--assume-unchanged` and/or `--skip-worktree`.  These show up as flag letters in `git ls-files -v` output.

Hence, `git ls-files` is the command to use for everything: you just have to use it *more than once*, and take further actions based on the first one's output.

(To script `git ls-files`, use the `-z` option.  See my [`git flagged` command](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged) for an example.)